# To run a dialog box as a result of clicking a button in quickly using python

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

I am developing an application that has various buttons such as addition, multiplication and so on.. now when I click on addition button I want a dialog box to be displayed that has labels n text inputs (design part). I am facing a problem with linking that dialog box to the button..
Please tell me step by step how to initialize it and what should be written under this :

def on_addition_clicked(self, widget):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to defining the functions to be called, you must connect the signal of the button.
The easiest way to do this is to define a dict with a mapping from the names to the handlers and then pass it to the `Gtk.Builder.connect_signals()` method. Read [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html#connecting-signals) for more help.